# shower valve type?

Tags: shower, delta

The house came with a Delta shower valve.  When I went to replace it with a Kohler valve and trim kit, I found that the Kohler cartridge doesn't appear to mount to the rough in valve.
From what I can tell I have this [Delta universal](https://www.build.com/product/summary/661432?uid=188434) rough in.
Am I correct that I have a mismatch?
This is the new Kohler cartridge
[image]
[image]

And this is the existing Delta cartridge (still trying to get it out).
[image]

**EDIT**
Okay, I got it out, and they definitely do not match.
[image]
So does Kohler make a valve that'll fit this "rough in"?

Comment: Delta has a pretty wide range of cartridges and trim, but you will have to stay "in brand". The major brands are not compatible with each other by design.  I'm happy to have Delta because I know I'll always be able to find parts, so consider yourself lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Kohler cartridge will not fit into your Delta valve. You will need to get a Delta replacement cartridge or replace the valve with the right Kohler valve. Yes, you do have a mismatch. You need to get the old cartridge out first and then go from there to get a replacement.

Comment: yeah, I updated the post with what I pulled out. Do you know if Kohler makes a cartridge like that?

Comment: If you really want to use Kohler, you'll probably have to replace more than just the cartridge

Comment: @Aaron  Kohler is in a class all it's own (like Apple) and I doubt they make a cartridge that will fit a Delta valve.  Your only hope is visiting a plumbing supply store and see if they have what you need.

Comment: Turns out this part has a lifetime warranty from Delta, so they are sending me a new one!